# How to load the cms page inside custom phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

Is this possible to load the cms page/ category inside custom phtml file, if it is possible how we can load cms page/ category inside custom phtml file.

Thanks.

Comment: check this link https://meetanshi.com/blog/call-cms-static-block-in-phtml-file-in-magento-2/

Comment: HI @MohitPatel ,its about calling block, but i need about calling page

Comment: check this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/magento-2-0-call-cms-page-in-phtml-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.0 Call cms page in phtml file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/magento-2-0-call-cms-page-in-phtml-file)

Answer (score 0):

Your phtml is rendered by a block class.
You need to add this in your block class.

```
protected $pageFactory;
protected $brandPage;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    ....
){
    ....
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    ....
}

public function getBrandsPageContent()
{
    if (is_null($this->brandPage)) {
        $this->brandPage = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $this->brandPage->load('brand_list', 'identifier');
    }
    return $this->brandPage->getContent();
}
```

then in your phtml you just call  `echo $this->getBrandsPageContent()`

Comment: It's not very professional copy someone else answer from comment specified above as own answer

Comment: Hi @Gohil Rajesh, what is "barnd_list", "identifier" here, we dont have any identifier for the page!

Comment: @Mani every page has must be unique identifier. it means url key of your page

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk I am just trying to help here. I believe instead of adding link its better to post answer. I can clarify their doubts too